# How to convert decimal to time format? kotlin Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

```kotlin
val duration = df.format(videoView!!.duration.toLong() / 100000.0)
```

duration gives the answer in decimals e.g 0.45 I want to make it like 0:45.

(these are in seconds, I dont want to display units. Writing this info in brackets just for reference)

Comment: In what language?

Answer (score 0):

Dividing milliseconds by 100,000 doesn't really give you anything. It is much better to divide by 1000 (not by 1000.0. Because, you will probably not need milliseconds, you can also round to closest integer value, but that's up to you):

`val durationInSeconds:Int = df.format(videoView!!.duration.toLong() / 1000)`

Then you can calculate minutes by dividing `duratinInSeconds` by 60 (result is integer).

`val minutes:Int = durationInSeconds/60`

Then you calculate seconds:

`val seconds:Int = durationInSeconds%60`

Lastly you combine `minutes` and `seconds`:

`val minutesAndSeconds = "%2d:%2d".format(minutes,seconds)`

Answer (score 0):

I would first try to get my time value either in seconds or in milliseconds and then try to format it something like this:

```
//t is given in seconds
fun formatTime(t: Int) : String{
    var hours = t / 3600
    var minutes = (t % 3600) / 60
    var seconds = t % 60

    return "$hours:$minutes:$seconds"
}
print(formatTime(12345)) //prints 3:25:45
```